# Access permission for firebase crashlytics project

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to access a BigQuery dataset but it is showing that I don't have access permission to the dataset. So, can you please tell me, is my Firebase Project Owner will give me access permission? Can you send me the process to access a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, apps are organized into projects. When your Project Owner exporting data to BigQuery, he owns that data, and can use BigQuery [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) to manage permissions on projects and datasets. See controlling access to datasets [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls). The user who wants to view the mentioned dataset needs to be granted the corresponding permissions, probably in your case it should be `bigquery.dataViewer` role, which allows you to read the dataset's metadata and list/read data from the dataset's tables.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Yes. If you are not familiar with this process, the project owner should go to the desired dataset in his Google Cloud Console -> BigQuery, click on [share dataset], write your Google Cloud account in the box and select "BigQuery Viewer" as a role, then click add. He could also go the GCP -> IAM seciton and just give you "BigQuery Viewer" permissions and you could then see all of his BQ tables.

Comment: Exactly, this is said in controlling access to datasets documentation.